# Expecting the text entered in the searchbox to be printed on the results page

Tags: python, html, django

views.py

```
    from weatherbot.models import Question
    from django.template import RequestContext
    from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

    def search(request):
        query = request.GET.get('q')
        if query:
            results = query
        context = RequestContext(request)
        return render_to_response('results.html', {"results": results,}, context_instance=context)
```

urls.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from . import views

    urlpatterns = [ 
url(r'^search/$', views.search, name = 'Ask for Weather Updates'),]
```

search.html

```
    <form method="get" action="/search/">
     Search Notecards:<input type="text" name="q" id="id_q" value="{{ query }}"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
```

result.html

```
    {% if results %}
      {% for result in results %}
        {{ result.xxxx }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
    <h3 class='error'>Please enter a valid UID</h3>
    <form method="get" action="//">
     Search Notecards:<input type="text" name="q" id="id_q" value="{{ query }}"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
    {% endif %}
```

What i am trying to do is to first enter a question in the searchbox and then display it in the results page using django

Comment: Please post your code here instead of linking to a paste bin, fix the indentation, and explain in more detail what you expect to happen and what actually happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view, `results` is a string, so `{% for result in results %}` will loop through each letter in the string, and `{{ result.xxxx }}` will not display anything because strings don't have an `xxxx` attribute.

I would replace that loop in the template with simply:

```
{{ results }}
```

You can simplify your view to use `render` instead of `render_to_response`. Since you have `if query`, you also have to set `query` in the `else` statement, otherwise you'll get a name error.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        results = query
    else:
        results = ''
    return render_to_response(request, 'results.html', {"results": results,})
```

You might find the [forms chapter](http://masteringdjango.com/django-forms/) from Mastering Django useful.

Comment: thanks for the answer and the link!!!